# Como realizar una consulta Inner Join en Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carrera = models.TextField()
    promocion = models.TextField()
    telefono = models.TextField(max_length=11)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    imagen = models.ImageField(null=True)
    area = models.ManyToManyField(area_conocimiento)

class publicacion(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=True, related_name='publicacion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    canal = models.ForeignKey(canal, editable=True, related_name='canal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contenido = models.TextField()
    imagen = models.ImageField(null=True)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tipo = models.TextField()
```

Necesito mostrar todas las publicaciones hechas por usuarios cuya promoción sea igual a la de un determinado usuario (en este caso 56),
la siguiente consulta me funciona sin problemas en la base de datos:

```
SELECT redsocial_publicacion.usuario_id, redsocial_publicacion.contenido, redsocial_publicacion.canal
FROM redsocial_perfil, redsocial_publicacion, auth_user
WHERE redsocial_publicacion.canal = 'promo'
AND redsocial_publicacion.usuario_id = redsocial_perfil.usuario_id
AND redsocial_perfil.promocion = '56'
AND redsocial_publicacion.usuario_id = auth_user.id
```

Intente haciendo lo siguiente en **Django** pero sin resultado:

```
publicaciones_promo =  publicacion.objects.filter(tipo="publico",canal='promo', perfil__promocion=promo_usuario)
```

Comment: le falta información a esta pregunta, la estructura de la tabla, la salida esperada.

Comment: ¿Qué resultado está arrojando y qué debería arrojar? veo bien la consulta, con la diferencia que te falta hacer el filtro por el id del usuario.

Comment: Creo que `promocion` debe ser un campo `models.ForeingKey` del modelo `perfil`. La consulta sería muy simple de esa manera.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, al final logré solucionarlo de otra forma.